# fscanf not returning EOF or fscanf going to infinite loop in C

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I am trying to write a few lines to a file. After the line are written, when I try to read those lines from file using `fscanf` it is going into infinite loop. `fprintf` is working but `fscanf` is going to an infinite loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

  void main()
       {
        FILE *fp;
        int roll;
        char name[25];
        float marks;
        char ch;
        fp = fopen("file.txt","w");           
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nCan't open file or file doesn't exist.");
            exit(0);
        }

        do
        {
             printf("\nEnter Roll : ");
             scanf("%d",&roll);

             printf("\nEnter Name : ");
             scanf("%s",name);
             printf("\nEnter Marks : ");
             scanf("%f",&marks);

             fprintf(fp,"%d%s%f",roll,name,marks);

             printf("\nDo you want to add another data (y/n) : ");
             ch = getche();

             }while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');

            printf("\nData written successfully...");
              
              
              
            printf("\nData in file...\n");

            while((fscanf(fp,"%d%s%f",&roll,name,&marks))!=EOF)
            printf("\n%d\t%s\t%f",roll,name,marks);
                
              

            fclose(fp);
       }
```

Comment: Print useful error messages, write them to stderr, and exit non-zero on a fatal error. eg: `const char *path = "file.txt"; fp = fopen(path,"w");  if(fp == NULL) { perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: Never use `%s` without a maximum field width that is at most one less than the size of the buffer being written to.  eg `scanf("%24s",name);`

Comment: You've opened the file for writing.  Why do you expect `fscanf` to work at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opened the file for writing (mode "w"), so your `scanf` calls are almost certainly failing.  Even if you fix the mode, it is not at all surprising that:

```
while((fscanf(fp,"%d%s%f",&roll,name,&marks))!=EOF)
```

goes into an infinite loop.  If the next character in the stream is not a valid character in an integer, then `scanf` will return zero and not consume it.  It will repeatedly attempt to read that character as an integer and repeatedly fail.  The correct approach here is probably to stop using `scanf` entirely, but a quick work-around may be something like:

```
int rv;
while( (rv = fscanf(fp,"%d%s%f",&roll,name,&marks)) != EOF ){
    if( rv == 3 ){
        printf(...);
    } else {
        /* probably the right thing to do is break out of
           the loop and emit an error message, but maybe 
           you just want to consume one character to progress
           in the stream. */
        if( fgetc(fp) == EOF ){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

it would be more common to write `while( 3 == fscanf(...))` and just emit an error message on bad input, but something like the above kludge might be useful (depending on your use case).

But you need to fix the open mode.  Probably you just want to close the file after the write loop (you certainly need to flush it before you can expect to read from the file) and re-open in with mode "r".